# I'm trying to install ubuntu on another partition

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, boot-partition

I'm trying to install ubuntu on another partition. I have an SSD, where Windows 10 is installed and I have a HD, where I want to install Ubuntu. I had tried to install normally, but it did not even go through GRUB. Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Did you install in same boot mode as Windows. Most Windows 10 systems are UEFI, only those that are upgrades from Windows 7 may be BIOS/MBR. Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot, only use ppa download into Ubuntu live installer.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I do not have UEFI. I want, for example, to leave windows on SSD and ubuntu in HD.

Comment: Then only use Something Else and install to HDD, and be sure to choose to install grub2's boot loader to the HDD, leaving Windows boot loader on SSD. Then in BIOS set HDD as default and you can boot both Windows & Ubuntu from grub menu. And if Windows has issues like when it turns fast start up back on, or needs chkdsk, you still can directly boot from BIOS and SSD.  If Ubuntu installed, you can use Boot-Repair to install grub to HDD drive. Can only give general info without report from Boot-Repair.